# Accidentally changed wp url in settings

Tags: wordpress

I accidentally changed wp url in settings and now I am locked out of my wp-admin dashboard for WP. I have found a lot of tutorials on fixing, however they only work if your host is supporting cpanel for database. My question is, how can I access database if I was given name, password, host etc. I have also access to a server with all the stored data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already got it! I just needed to download sql buddy to the server and access the database then just change the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover from this with FTP access; you can use MySQL/database access, but it's not required.

With FTP access, you can add a few lines to either `wp-config.php` or the theme's `functions.php` file.

Use this in `wp-config.php` to "hardcode" the URLs you need, i.e. the site URLs before you changed them in settings:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Or in the theme's `functions.php file`:

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

See [Changing The Site URL « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for more details about these and other recovery methods.